# WRITING: Is there any grammatical rule that prohibits multiple topics in one paragraph?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, vocabulary, writing, ielts

I came across an educator who teaches students to limit the number of topic sentence to only one(he is not a native English speaker).

Is this a widely agreed,valid rule for writing?Has there been such a custom established anywhere in the Anglo sphere?

Best regards

Comment: No, there is no such rule. But the longer a paragraph and the more elements it covers, the harder it is to digest. Best read a few articles, see what others do, and draw your own conclusions.

Comment: It's more 'style' than 'grammar'.

Comment: It's a common rule in writing guides that a paragraph should be about a single topic ([for example, from Purdue](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/academic_writing/paragraphs_and_paragraphing/index.html)) But this isn't grammar. It's just something that makes writing easier to understand, and in practice there may be reasons to deviate from it. If you want more advice on paragraphs and style, maybe try Writing SE.

Answer (score 1):

The division of a text into paragraphs is not at the level of "grammar".  It isn't concerned with how words are ordered or change form.

Instead it is one of the tools of the writer to structure their text and make it easier to understand for the reader. The principle is that you split up your writing into chunks.  The reader understands each chunk in turn.  By inserting paragraphs you signal to the reader the places that are best to pause and think about what you've written.

Now, in well-written essays there are all kinds of paragraphs.  Look at a skilled writer like [Margaret Atwood](https://whatrocks.github.io/commencement-db/1983-margaret-atwood-university-of-toronto/) or [Neil Gaiman](https://www.neilgaiman.com/Cool_Stuff/Essays/Essays_By_Neil/Where_do_you_get_your_ideas%253F). See how they paragraph.

So why do teachers suggest you must use 1 topic sentence, an explanation sentence, 4-7 sentences per paragraph, etc etc?  [It makes them easy to mark](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/the-five-paragraph-method).  It is easier to teach "rules" than to just say "write well".  If you can already write well, you don't need these rules.  The rules are just a easy-to-teach and easy-to-learn summary of what good writing is. They are painting-by-numbers, and can help learners avoid the worst mistakes.